# Django cursor dictfetchall is not returning the dictionary correctly

Tags: python, django

I'm using the dictfetchall from the Django documentation in order to return a dictionary for use in AJAX GET.

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

In this function:

```
def UserData(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT user_id, email FROM users_user LIMIT 2")
    row = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return HttpResponse(row)
```

And supposedly it should be returning this:

```
[{'user_id': 4, 'email': 'ewoif@rjhior.com'}, {'user_id': 25, 'email': 'efweew@ferfr.com'}]
```

But it is returning this:

```
{'user_id': 4, 'email': 'ewoif@rjhior.com'}{'user_id': 25, 'email': 'efweew@ferfr.com'}
```

No [ ] and no comas ,

Why?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return JsonResponse(row, safe=False)
```

Comment: I figured out that when I do the HttpResponse, the [ ] and commas don't show up, even though they are there because they show in the print().
And yeah, using the JsonResponse(row, safe=False) does the job, thanks